# How should I design software to communicate with a server and a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting a homework which asks me to build a small software. This software has to do the following things:

1. The user can operate from the user-side app by clicking buttons / entering texts
2. The user-side app has to upload the user inputs to the server
3. The server has to gather all users' inputs, generate a summary (like the average number of a category entered by all users) and display it on a webpage

My questions are:

a. To upload the user inputs (step 2 above), I plan to link my user-side app with mysql instructions, so I can send the data to a mysql database on my server. Does it sound reasonable?

b. On the server side (step 3 above), do I need to worry about the order of the data sent to mysql when multiple users are operating? 
It is possible to store data according to each user's entries and then do the calculation (like take the average of a category of all users') every 2 mins. However, can I program the server to dynamically calculate the average? For example, as long as there is a new input, the server update the average and display. If possible, should I be modifying the server-side program like my webpage which displays the average number? Or, can I program the database to let it calculate the average and stores the number when new data arrives?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The best way to learn is to take an idea and try it.

Comment: This is not the right forum to ask such questions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us the parameters of your environment. What technologies do you use/should you use/do you plan to use? Also, please write a correct English title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've outlined some pretty core issues, and there are many ways you could proceed.

To answer your particular questions, I'd offer this;

a. Given that you have tagged your question as PHP, I am guessing you would want to use that as your server-side code for your business logic (i.e. receiving your form input and doing any server-side calculations). This is also how you would perform any CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations for persisting with your database.

b. If you are designing for multiple users, your database domain model would need to reflect that, and your form input would need to capture something like a 'username' field which your PHP logic uses to direct the persistence correctly. Your ordering is established through how you build that server-side logic for a given user. You mentioned some sort of aggregating of user data every two minutes. This can be done with a polling feature perhaps, but again, there are many design considerations to evaluate. I'd suggest a Google search for php and polling to see what can be done here. It's not clear to me what your display goal is, but however you proceed, I'd suggest keeping your logic in a PHP service layer, your persistence data (model) in the mysql database, and a view layer that is bound to that data however you need.

You might benefit from reviewing PHP tutorials:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

and doing a Google search for MVC (Model-View-Controller) design.

Hope this helps.